# CSS Float issue within grid

Tags: css, sass, css-float

I am aiming to create a simple image grid using css floats with certain 'featured' blocks which are double the size of the others.

I have it mostly working fine however when a block is featured I'm unable to get the next block to fit underneath it correctly.

I've included a jsfiddle to make the problem much clearer. You will see that at the bottom of the output there is a block on a row of it's own to the right of the featured element (with the class 'problem'). I would like this to instead be on the left of the featured block and on the same row as it is currently so that I can add another 2 blocks to create a completed grid but I can't work out how.

CSS:

```
.grid {
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        li {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            white-space: nowrap;
            list-style: none;
            line-height: 0;
            img {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
    .featured {
        width: 40%;
    }
}
```

(Nested css is due to scss).

Full fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/thillin/y2hvxokf/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: add feature class to your `.g1` instead `.g2`

Comment: Probably not going to be solvable using floats. I'd suggest a JS Solution like [**masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Technically this is called `Dynamic Grid Layout`**

As per your requirement you have to use jquery here because there is no solid solution available using only css and html.

There are ready made plugins available online.

You can see or download the demo from here:

[Reference 1:](http://masonry.desandro.com)

[Reference 2:](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Dynamic-Grid-Layout-Plugin.html)